# Develop a function that cleans up a phone number entered by a user - Homework Warning

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I cannot get my third else if to return array[2] without the last number. Any help on where im going wrong on the slice, much appreciated.

> Question: Develop a function that cleans up a phone number entered by
>   a user.
>   The rules are as follows:
>
> - If the phone number is less than 10 digits or more than 11 digits, assume that it is bad number
> - If the phone number is 10 digits assume that it is good
> - If the phone number is 11 digits and the first number is 1, trim the 1 and use the last 10 digits
> - If the phone number is 11 digits and the first number is not 1, then it is a bad number.
>
> HINT: You may need to use the charAt method.

```
var phoneNumbers = ["456799", "1234567898", "12345678911", "23456789101"];   

function phoneNumberCleanUp(array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if ((array[i].length < 10) && (array[i].length > 11)) {
            console.log("This is a bad number: " + array[i]);

        } else if (array[i].length === 10) {
            console.log("This is a good number: " + array[i]);

        } else if ((array[i].length === 11) && (array[i].charAt(0) === "1")) {
            console.log("This is a good number: " + array[i].slice(array[i].length, -1));

        } else if ((array[i].length === 11) && (array[i].charAt(0) !== 1)) {
            console.log("This is a bad number also: " + array[i]);

        } else {
            console.log("This is a bad number too: " + array[i]);
        }
    }
  }

phoneNumberCleanUp(phoneNumbers);
```

Comment: You don't need the last `else if` check. Just fix the slicing (see my answer below) and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Simple fix: `else if ((array[i].length === 11) && (array[i].charAt(0) !== '1'))`

Compare against the string of 1, not the number 1. Slicing at that point is also a little different:

`console.log("This is a good number: " + array[i].slice(1, array[i].length));`

Personally, I'd write it more like this:

```
var phoneNumbers = ["456799", "1234567898", "12345678911", "23456789101"];

const phoneNumberCleanUp = phoneNumbers => {
    phoneNumbers.forEach(phoneNumber => {
      if (phoneNumber.length === 10)
        console.log('This is a good number:', phoneNumber);
      else if ((phoneNumber.length === 11) && phoneNumber.startsWith('1'))
        console.log('This is a good number:', phoneNumber.substring(1));
      else
        console.log('This is a bad number:', phoneNumber);
    });
};
phoneNumberCleanUp(phoneNumbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

the === operator and !== operator compare also the types of the variables ,however the == and != operators compare only the value,because of that 1 == '1' return true, first he convert them to the same type and then compare their value , but 1 === '1' return false because 1 is integer and "1" is a string and he compare also the type.

**Quoted from JavaScript The Definitive Guide 6th Edition:**

The equality operator == is like the strict equality operator (===), but it is less strict. If the values of the two operands are not the same type, it attempts some type conversions and tries the comparison again.

**And**

The strict equality operator === evaluates its operands, and then compares the two values as follows, performing no type conversion.

so keep your !== operator but change your 1 to '1' .

and for your second else if i will use substring from the 1 index, 10 chars forward

```
function phoneNumberCleanUp(array) {
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if ((array[i].length < 10) && (array[i].length > 11)) {
                console.log("This is a bad number: " + array[i]);

            } else if (array[i].length === 10) {
                console.log("This is a good number: " + array[i]);

            } else if ((array[i].length === 11) && (array[i].charAt(0) === "1")) {
                console.log("This is a good number: " + array[i].substring(1 , 10));

            } else if ((array[i].length === 11) && (array[i].charAt(0) !== '1')) {
                console.log("This is a bad number also: " + array[i]);
            } else {
                console.log("This is a bad number too: " + array[i]);
            }
        }
      }
    phoneNumberCleanUp(phoneNumbers);
```